# Unable to execute Visual Studio bootstrapper vs_community.exe in Powershell (admin) and get error "not recognized..."

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to execute bootstrapper vs_community.exe for the edition of Visual Studio 2022 in PowerShell (admin) to create a local layout for offline installation on another computer.

I follow instructions from microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

```
vs_community.exe --layout c:\localVSlayout --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb --includeOptional --lang en-US
```

PowerShell returns error:

```
vs_community.exe : The term 'vs_community.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or ope
rable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again
.
At line:1 char:1
+ vs_community.exe --layout c:\localVSlayout --add Microsoft.VisualStud ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (vs_community.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How do I execute vs_community.exe correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that vs_community.exe is exist in current directory, and then try with .\vs_community.exe instead of vs_community.exe.
That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

run the command screen in the address bar of whatever folder the exe is in

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue for using single quotation(') for layout path:
*vs_Community.exe --layout 'C:\VisualStudio2022\Community'*

Using double quotation (") resolved the issue for me: "C:\VisualStudio2022\Community"